# how to set the pen color in InkCanvas

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Can anyone Suggest me the best way to change the drawing brush color of `InkCanvas`. i have the following xaml code,

```
<InkCanvas Margin="0,0,-3,-1" Background="Brown" Cursor="Pen" Gesture="InkCanvas_Gesture" Name="inkcanvas"/>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Include these lines in your xaml:

```
<InkCanvas>
      <InkCanvas.DefaultDrawingAttributes >
                        <DrawingAttributes
         Color = "White" Width = "6" />
      </InkCanvas.DefaultDrawingAttributes>
</InkCanvas>
```

Comment: I like this, I want this in XAML not code behind, but Windows 10 UWP doesn't seem to recognize DefaultDrawingAttributes attached property, any ideas on why or how to work around this?

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
InkCanvas.DefaultDrawingAttributes.Color = Colors.SpringGreen;
```

for details see Example section in [MSDN Documentation of InkCanvas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.inkcanvas%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Where i want to use this

Answer (score 0):

```
inkcanvas.DefaultDrawingAttributes.Color = Colors.Blue;
```